# Traduction de « quid pro quo »

Tags: traduction, anglais, latin

En anglais on a le « *quid pro quo* » :

> [quid pro quo](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=quid%20pro%20quo)
>   n. pl. quid pro quos also quids pro quo
>  Something that is given
>   in return for something else or accepted as a reciprocal part of an
>   exchange.
>  [Latin quid prō quō : quid, something + prō, for + quō,
>   ablative of quid, something.]
>
> [ *The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language* - «
>   *quid pro quo* » ]

On peut parler en partie d'une [*contrepartie*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/quid-pro-quo). Il faut [noter](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/55506) qu'il ne s'agit pas de la/du « *[m]éprise, malentendu faisant prendre une personne, une chose pour une autre* », c'est-à-dire un [*quiproquo*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quiproquo) en français ou dans les autres [langues romanes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quid_pro_quo#Other_meanings), mais plutôt d'une idée similaire à celle qu'exprime la locution latine [*do ut des*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_ancient_Roman_religion#do_ut_des) (« I give that you might give »). [Merriam-Websters Learner's](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/quid%20pro%20quo) présente cet exemple : « If he helps us, he'll expect a *quid pro quo*. [=he'll expect us to do something for him] » (voir aussi [*Cambridge*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/quid-pro-quo)).

---

Dans une scène du film *Silence of the Lambs* (1991, *J. Demme*), le personnage du *docteur Lecter* s'exprime [ainsi](https://youtu.be/YlRLfbONYgM) :

> [...] If I help you, Clarice, it will be "turns" with us too. *Quid pro
>   quo*. I tell you things, you tell me things. Not about this case,
>   though. About yourself. *Quid pro quo*. Yes or no? [...]

Je n'ai jamais visionné ce film en langue française alors je ne sais pas pour quelle solution on aura opté ici (et ce n'est pas pertinent en soi) mais j'aimerais bien savoir comment on peut le rendre par un mot, une locution ou une expression dans ce contexte en traduisant l'extrait en français ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puisqu'il s'agit d'une locution latine, elle être utilisée telle quelle, et elle l'est de temps à autre.

Il n'y a cependant pas de « traduction standard » pour *quid pro quo*. Toute locution qui rend l'idée d'un échange quelconque passe. Une expression possible est *donnant donnant*.

> ***[Donnant donnant](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/donnant)***
>
> *En emploi de gérondif, loc. proverbiale.* Pour signifier qu'on ne veut donner une chose qu'en recevant une autre chose.

C'est personnellement ce que j'aurais utilisé pour l'extrait du *Silence des agneaux*, mais Lecter parle plutôt d'*[échanges de bons procédés](https://youtu.be/6WYDAIJcius?t=86)*.

On peut également parler de *contrepartie* ou de *compensation*, tels que les mentionnent [Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=&index=alt&__index=alt&srchtxt=quid%20pro%20quo) et le [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/quid_pro_quo).

Comment: Nos réponses (simultanées) sont très proches, il n'y a plus rien d'intéressant à conserver dans la mienne qui ne soit aussi dans la tienne, donc je me retire pour éviter l'effet doublon.

Comment: Ajoutons que l'emploi de l'expression *échange de bons procédés* est excellente, car elle remplace par le ton l'effet de sophistication apporté par le latin dans la version anglaise, que l'on perd un peu avec *donnant donnant* qui sonne probablement trop terre-à-terre et pragmatique dans la bouche de ce personnage éminemment romantique.

Comment: Merci! _Donnant donnant_ c'est excellent. Si un francophone me disait  "un quid pro quo" sans contexte, personnellement je me poserais des questions sur le sens, maintenant que je sais le sens anglais. Si Hannibal le disait au lieu d'échange de bons procédés, je me dirais maintenant que c'est une "translittération" et vu le personnage je rechercherais le sens anglais. Merci aussi d'avoir trouvé la séquence et les emplois particuliers en comptabilité!

Comment: @RomainVALERI Excellent commentaire! En plus du ton, dans la locution il y a le mot "échange" et ça s'imbrique parfaitement avec le sens du "barter".

Answer (score 2):

I generally try to avoid Latin phrases, but when I encounter “*quid pro quo*” in English, I generally interpret it as capturing the notion of “the reciprocation/return of favors/actions” and my two preferred informal/familiar phrases for expressing this notion are:

> “*scratch my back, I’ll scratch yours*” (always for favors) and
>   “*tit for tat*” (more neutral, sometimes for favors, but sometimes for
>   vengeful actions).

These two English phrases lead me to the respective notions of “[renvoyer l’ascenseur](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/renvoyer_l%E2%80%99ascenseur)” (always positive, as far as I know) and “[rendre la pareille](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rendre_la_pareille)” (neutral) in French. Therefore, perhaps a French *Hannibal* could have said:

> “[Principe de] *renvoyer l’ascenseur*”;
>  “[Principe de] *la pareille
>   rendue/rendre la pareille*”;

or even, going back to the notion of “reciprocation” for a more formal option:

> “[L'idée/principe de] *réciprocité*” (instead of “quid pro quo.”)

(but see the clip provided in Kareen’s good answer as well as [these](http://context2.reverso.net/bitexte.php?q=quid%20pro%20quo&bitexte=PUBLIC!MOVIE!MOVIE-202!202&langFrom=en&langTo=fr) two [translations](http://context2.reverso.net/bitexte.php?q=quid%20pro%20quo&bitexte=PUBLIC!MOVIE!MOVIE-5286!559&langFrom=en&langTo=fr) where Hannibal, apparently in two other scenes, uses “quid pro quo” in French.)

Comment: Thank you! Un _renvoi d'ascensceur_ +1! At the same time it is harder to wield those without conjugating the verbs or using sth. such as "il faut" etc. So sometimes focusing on one very meaningful word to convey an idea can work like _réciprocité_ you mention. Also looked at the 2 trans.; I would make the same comment as on the other answer and I find it all quite interesting. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by *un renvoi d'ascenseur* I found useful to also cite the more familiar (but neutral) *un prêté pour un rendu*.

It would just post that in a comment, but I suddenly remembered how Coluche (a French humorist which died 30 years ago) had turned this formula, and I thought it would be interesting for our English readers to have a comprehension of this wordplay.

Rather than *un prêté pour un rendu*, Coluche said *un prêté pour un vomi*.
He played with the babyish sense of *rendre* for *regurgitate* or *vomit*, so giving a paradoxical (hence comic) tone to the formula, since the positive sense of *rendu* becames negative with *vomi*.

Comment: So my mentioning "un renvoi d'ascenseur" helped to inspire all of that!!?? Cool! +1